# Reversing the array without any additional buffer

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Can you please advise how to reverse an array without using an additional buffer , which is the best algorithm to achieve this as for example i have the below class consists of an array  , i am looking for the best algorithm so that i do not need to create an extra buffer or an extra array while reversing the array

```
public class ardem
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

}
}
```

well I don't want to use any predefined method of api i want to create my own please advise how to achieve this

Comment: Please, please learn to format your code.

Comment: @Boris Thanks i will make sure to format

Comment: @Alex please share the duplicate question url also

Comment: @user1620642 You can't click on the link????

Comment: @AlexisC. sorry , yeah i have checked thanks

Answer (score 0):

There already  exists an implementation of it:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```

in [Commons.Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).